# Add an extra Capital letter element only at the start of each new letter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array sorted like so:

```
[aa,ab,ba,bb]
```

I want to render it like this:

```
A
aa
ab
B
ba
bb
```

how can I modify this forech to do this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array" >
{{item}} <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
$scope.capitalize = function(array){
    //group all elements by first letter using lodash
    var items = _.groupBy(array,function(element){return element.charAt(0)});
    //flatten object arrays to one array
    return _.flatten(items,function(elements,letter){return [letter.toUpperCase(),elements] });

}
```

and on html you have

```
<div ng-repeat="item in capitalize(array)">
        {{item}} <br/>
</div>
```

Working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/qmw0qp6p/4/

I added also @sameer resolution, but it is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to print the words and their first letters like you did in the question, but more like this:

```
A
- aa
- ab
B
- ba
- bb
```

To do so, I would aggregate the strings by their first letter using a custom `groupBy` filter (reusable), and then simply loop on the obtained object.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmc9p0gu/1/).

The cache system I implemented allows fast access to already computed results and avoids infinite digest loop (occurring because a new object is each time returned by [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below code

```
angular.module('module', []).
  filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input, all) {
      return (!!input) ? input.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}) : '';
    }
  });
```

and In HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array" >
{{item | capitalize}} <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question